# Immutablity of collection scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

In an immutable collection in Scala a new object is created when the length of the collection changes. Let's suppose I create an immutable array and then perform concatenation:

```
object Dcoder extends App
{
    var array=Array("abc","xyz")
    var change =array++Array("change of object")
}
```

Does the new object gets created because of `++`? Since I'm using an immutable collection and its length has changed, is the object creation caused by the change?

Comment: Array in scala is not immutable, just fixed-length.

Comment: Thanxx puheln , I was thinking that like List arrays r also mutable and immutable..

Comment: Arrays are fixed-length, so you can't add or remove elements, but the are still mutable.  You can modify any of the elements inside it.  Immutable collections are like List or Vector, which can't be changed at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutablity of collection Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180300/immutablity-of-collection-map)

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling the ++ method on your Array object (documentation https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) using infix notation (https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)