# Immutablity of collection Map

Tags: scala-collections

In  immutable collection of SCALA a new object is created when length of collection changes Let us suppose I create a immutable Map and then perform concatenation.
CODE=>

```
object Dcoder extends App
{
    var map=Map("abc"-> 1,"xyz"->2)
    var change =map++Map("change of object"+>3)
}
```

Now my Question is 
a) Does the new object gets created because of ++ ??
b) Since I'm using a IMMUTABLE COLLECTION and length of Immutable collection has  changed so new object is created ??

Comment: The size of an immutable collection cannot change because it is immutable. Rather, a new collection is created by the operation. The original `map` object remains intact.

Comment: Can u plss explain with eg

Comment: So immutablity && ++ both are responsible for new objects ??

Comment: Not sure what "responsible" means, CS is not a place for metaphors. The methods instantiate new objects. There's likely some sharing of underlying data structures between the original and the newly created objects, but they are both immutable — the holy grail of functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `++` [immutable.Map.++](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#++[V1%3E:V](xs:scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[(K,V1)]):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,V1]):

```
Adds a number of elements provided by a traversable object and returns a new collection with the added elements.
```

So indeed, it creates a new collection, remaining the old `map` unmodified:

```
scala> var map = Map("abc" -> 1, "xyz" -> 2)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 1, xyz -> 2)

scala> var change = map ++ Map("change of object" -> 3)
change: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 1, xyz -> 2, change of object -> 3)

scala> change
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 1, xyz -> 2, change of object -> 3)

scala> map
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 1, xyz -> 2)
```

You can use `+=` to "modify" your `map` likewise:

```
scala> map += "lol" -> 3

scala> map
res12: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(abc -> 1, xyz -> 2, lol -> 3)
```

Realize that I just put "modify", because this returns another `map` (since it's immutable) object and assigns it to your `map` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both questions. In fact, according to [scala docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html):

```
ms ++ kvs
```

creates map containing all mappings of ms as well as all key/value pairs of kvs.
More info [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html).